# How can I define a boolean based on stage width?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, layout, performance, boolean

I'm trying to create a dynamic layout for a flex app.

I need a boolean which is dependent upon the overall width of the browser window with which to set states, something along the lines of

```
    if(this.parentApplication.width<950)
        {
            currentState = "wide"   
        }else{
            currentState = "narrow"
        }
```

However, I can't just state this in the fx:Script tags, so what is the best way to implement this? `enterFrame="application1_enterFrameHandler(event)"` works, but I can't help but feel like this is probably unnecessary and horribly computation intensive (and my application runs slow enough as it is, expect a question or two relating to flex efficiencies in the near future).

Thanks

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indeed waiting for a resize will be cheaper and more elegant.
in as3 the **S**tage class doesn't exist anymore and is replaced by **s**tage.
the syntax might not work either (as3 doesn't like anonymous functions very much :) ).

you'll need the stage to be available ([check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863706/purpose-of-init-function/4864253#4864253) for instance) and then 
put something like:

```
[...when stage is available...]
stage.addEventListener( Event.RESIZE, onResizeHandler );

onResizeHandler( null );//calling the method with an null event to force a first check
[...other instructions...]
```

and then

```
private function onResizeHandler( e:Event ):void
{
    currentState = ( stage.stageWidth < 950 ) ? 'wide' : 'narrow';
    //or testing a given object's width rather than the stage.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an event handler.

```
myListener = new Object();
myListener.onResize = function() {
  currentState = (obj.parentApplication.width<950) ? 'wide' : 'narrow';
};
Stage.addListener(myListener);
```

Sorry my ActionScript is a little rusty, it's been a while, but you'll probably have to change the `obj.parentApp...`, as far as I know, using `this` in here would refer to the arguments usually passed through the callback function.

**Edit**: Forgot to mention what happens.. basically the anonymous function gets triggered when the movie stage is resized by the user.. a lot less expensive than checking every frame event.