# Why do some classes have an init() method?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is `init()` function run once you instantiate it?

For example:

```
var circle:MovingCircle = new MovingCircle();
```

`MovingCircle` class has an `init()` function inside it.

Can someone enlighten me with `init()` function?

Another question is:

What's the difference between `MovieClip`, `Shape` and `Sprite` classes and when is it appropriate to use each?

Comment: Try to avoid asking multiple questions in a single post.

Comment: is it against the site's rule?
if it is sorry for this one.

Answer (score 4):

Great answer by Marty above; but there is another; slightly more subtle reason to use the following class structure:

```
public class WobbleBobble {
    // Constructor.
    public function WobbleBobble() {
        init();
    }

    private function init() : void {
        // ...<snip>some complex initialisation logic</snip>....
    }
}
```

You may be wondering why the the constructor calls the init() method; why not just put the complex initialisation logic block inside the constructor?

The answer is because the [AVM doesn't JIT code placed inside a constructor](http://blog.classsoftware.com/index.cfm/2010/11/4/Heavy-constructor-JIT-optimisation-in-ActionScript); which results in it executing about 70% slower than code in other methods.

[Related StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650714/actionscript-3-init).

Comment: That's really interesting. Kinda glad I rarely use constructors now. Good read. +1

Comment: why is the init() in that code private?
would you be able to access it with your constructor having a public access modifier?
is it possible that a calling function can access another function with a different access modifier?

Comment: Hi Christian; the visibility modifiers (private, protected, public) only apply to code outside of the current Class.  So a public method of Class A can call a private method of Class A, but not a private method of Class B.

Answer (score 3):

A constructor would be what you're thinking of when you say "run once your initialise it".

A constructor uses the same name as the class, eg:

```
public class Pants extends MovieClip
{
    public function Pants()
    {
        trace('hello');
    }
}
```

Now if we do:

```
var p:Pants = new Pants();
```

This code will be run also:

```
trace('hello');
```

An `init()` function would be a custom function that people might use as an asynchronous constructor (ie a function you can call after you've defined other variables and such).

```
public class Pants extends MovieClip
{
    public var str:String;

    public function init():void
    {
        trace(str);
    }
}
```

And then this would trace "some string":

```
var p:Pants = new Pants();

p.str = "some string";
p.init();
```

Personally, I use my own `init()` function within a setter of a base class for my application objects, like this:

```
public class Pants extends MovieClip
{
    private var _core:ApplicationCore;

    private function _init():void
    {
        trace("application core is: " + _core);
    }

    public function set core(ac:ApplicationCore):void
    {
        _core = ac;
        _init();
    }

    public function get core():ApplicationCore{ return _core; }
}
```

Then I can do this:

```
var appCore:ApplicationCore = new ApplicationCore();

var p:Pants = new Pants();
p.core = appCore;
```

Which will run my `init()` function only after I've defined the application core.

---

As for your question of different types of classes - the goal is to use the most primitive form of a class possible.

If you just want a simple graphic that you can move around the screen, use `Shape`. If you want to define more complex graphics, use `Sprite`. If you want to be able to have timeline animation, use `MovieClip`.

Basically, there's no need to be creating a MovieClip when all you want to do is create a blue square, but you'll need to use MovieClip or Sprite if you want to add other DisplayObjects to it.

Comment: Actually, you can also add children in a Sprite object.

Comment: what does  ApplicationCore  here means?
and why is there set and get in your function names

Comment: another thing! why is the access modifier of _core is private?
and why would you make such a variable private in a class if you'll be instantiating it?

Comment: It's private because I want it to be read-only via the getter I defined. ApplicationCore is just an example class.

Comment: sorry for this newbie question!:) what do you mean when you said read-only?

Comment: No worries. If you make a property private you can't access it from outside of the class itself. If you define a getter, then you can return the property which in turn makes it read only. So in my example, because there's this function: **public function get core()** I can access the value of **_core** as it's being returned.