# How to replace PureMVC Standard with PureMVC MultiCore

Tags: actionscript-3, module, migration, flash-builder, puremvc

I am working on a project, which uses PureMVC Standard.  Now I need to add a new module SWF, which also uses Standard.  I know the solution is to replace Standard MVC with MultiCore MVC, but there are two problems:

- Standard's package structure is different from MultiCore's - do I have to correct this manually?
- Under standard mvc framework, some code in the constructor of `Mediator` is allowed, while in MultiCore, this seems to be absolutely forbidden - so do I have to change so many constructors to get rid of this?

And finally: Other than replacing Standard with MultiCore, is there any better way to resolve the problem?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.  I took the liberty of improving your language and formatting.  Please check out the formatting sandbox to learn about how to make your questions more readable: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of any other good methods for changing the package structure, other than global search-and-replace across a project.  I have also not had problems doing this.

For Mediators, I have never had a problem with initializing simple variables (ints, Booleans, Arrays, etc) in the constructor, but anything else gets deferred to an onRegister (especially anything involving the stage in any way) and look something like:

```
public class MyMediator extends Mediator implements IMediator {
    public static const NAME : String = "MyMediator";

    // internal states
    private var foo : int;

    public function MyMediator (viewComponent : Object) {
        super(NAME, viewComponent);

        foo = 0;

        trace("MyMediator()", main_mc);
    }

    override public function onRegister () : void {
        main_mc.addEventListener(...);
    }

    protected function get main_mc () : Main {
        return viewComponent as Main;
    }
}
```

Having sparse contructors in AS3 is a good idea anyway, because [constructor code is always interpreted and not compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650714/actionscript-3-init).

Out of habit now, I use multicore for all projects, even when I have a single core.  This makes reusing mediators and proxies in new projects much easier.